# In Django, how do I trigger pdb to figure out what's causing a 404 when I don't know where to set a trace?

Tags: django, debugging

In my Django app, I'm getting a 404 Page Not Found response that looks like it's being caused by some logic in one of my custom template tags -- but I don't know which one.

Using Django Debug Toolbar's Request Vars panel, I can see the view causing the 404 is `go_back.utils._register_wrapped_view` -- which is how I know it's coming from one of my `go_back.utils` template tags.

Unfortunately, because template tags need to be decorated and thus show up as `_registered_wrapped_view`, I can't tell which tag it is, much less where in the tag code the problem happens. (The tag code is a special utility which works with urls and calls `resolve` in several places so it's not obvious.)

Thus I can't use the normal `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` approach because I don't know where to set the trace.

So how can I get pdb to break when the 404 happens so I can see the stack trace leading to that point?

Comment: Put pdb on the templatetag code or view class.

Comment: @TarsisAzevedo -- the issue is I don't know which template tag or view class is causing the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar), it can intercept redirects, good for when you cant find where to add a breakpoint.

In settings make sure you have

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do use Django Debug Toolbar. I had `INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS` set to False. No change in behavior when I set it to True. In the Request Vars panel, it shows the view as `go_back.utils._register_wrapped_view` -- which is how I know it's coming from one of my template tags (which are in the `go_back.utils` module). Unfortunately, because template tags need to be decorated and thus show up as `_registered_wrapped_view`, I can't tell which one it is.

Comment: Hmm.  The fact you get a 404 when its really a 500 sounds like Debug is off and Django cant find the 500 template, when standard behavior would be to print the exception detail page when DEBUG is True.  Also make sure TEMPLATE_DEBUG is true (equals DEBUG in default settings).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but there is [django-pdb](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb) which has a post mortem flag for runserver. It doesn't look well maintained (2 years ago is the last commit), but it is simple middleware and updating it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you know this:

You can try putting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the function which you want to debug and development server. When that function triggers it will break into `pdb` shell and you can debug your code.

Comment: Yep, I use that all the time. I need a post-mortem approach for this one, as I don't know which template tag or view is causing the problem.